# Interesting (new to me) things in the exposition of Landau's book on QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, measurement-problem, determinism

In section I.1 (The uncertainty principle), a principle I already know, the author suggests a "relaxing" picture (Unusual):

> "We have defined "apparatus" as a physical object which is governed, with sufficient accuracy, by classical mechanics. Such, for instance, is a body with large enough mass. However it must not be supposed that apparatus is necessarily macroscopic. Under certain conditions, the part of apparatus may be taken by an object which is microscopic, since the idea of "with sufficient accuracy" depends on the actual problem proposed. Thus, the motion of an electron in a Wilson chamber is observed by means of the cloudy track which it leaves, and the thickness of this is large compared with atomic dimensions; When the path is determined with such low accuracy, the electron is an entirely classical object."

So yes, it's a pretty thick path, but a path non the less. The electron does not seem to start acting too crazy if it is not getting smashed too hard.. So, what if it is not smashed at all? I'm not suggesting that the uncertainty relation/inequality is wrong (lol@me), but maybe it becomes just an equality in this case?

**(My original question, with that word.. determinism.. in it was my mistake.)**

Comment: Nature doesn't "know" anything about the distinction between the system under measurement and the measurement apparatus. Indeed, there is no distinction between either and the rest of the universe. I can't disagree with what Landau wrote because I don't have his book, but I am fairly sure that your interpretation of what Landau may have tried to say leads down a logical rabbit hole. Having said that, you are not the only one to go there. There is a whole school of thought that can't stop jumping trough hoops to rescue an understanding of determinism that didn't even work in the 19th century.

Comment: @CuriousOne +1 indeed. But just to be clear, I'm not at *all* trying to rescue determinism "between me and I". Obviously, anything microscopic meets apparatuses all day long. Even if it didn't, we would have to introduce one to it. But I'm not sure there is a logical rabbit hole here

Comment: They arr basically telling you that Schrodinger equationfor a closed system is determistic and time-reversible. But I would not call this in "a classical sense"

Comment: @Dror: I am simply saying that there was a tendency in the past to assume that macroscopic concepts were somehow more fundamental than microscopic ones. This lead to some rather heavy handed logical "plumbing" to reproduce the supposed effect that the measurement apparatus had on the measured quantum system. The opposite is much more straight beautiful and physical: take quantum mechanics seriously and calculate the residual effects on the macroscopic world.

Comment: @CuriousOne Rest assured I'm amazed by the beauty so far (And by the fact that a group of people (They were people after all) imagined and invented this paradigm), and I take it very seriously. I love looking at a "motionless" macroscopic spring and knowing that it physically cannot not oscillate (I know that it's waaay above the ground energy state, but regardless :)